# Getting Java JDK to compile on ubuntu

Tags: linux, java

I'm trying to start working with Java, but so far haven't been able to get it on my machine properly. I'd really like to be able to compile from command line. After following the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=332674) with no errors I can't compile with `javac`. Here's what I have so far:

When I enter:

```
$ java -version
```

I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_16"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)  
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

I get:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done  
Suggested packages:  
  sun-java6-demo sun-java6-doc sun-java6-source  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  sun-java6-jdk  
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.  
Need to get 17.4MB of archives.  
After this operation, 55.7MB of additional disk space will be used.  
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!  
  sun-java6-jdk  
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y  
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/multiverse sun-java6-jdk 6-07-3ubuntu2
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]  
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/s/sun-java6/sun-java6-jdk_6-07-3ubuntu2_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]  
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I run:

```
$ /media/disk/School/java/hw1$ javac HelloWorldApp,java  </pre>
```

I get:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:  
 * java-gcj-compat-dev  
 * openjdk-6-jdk  
 * gcj-4.2  
 * kaffe  
 * ecj  
 * jikes-sun  
 * jikes-sablevm  
 * j2sdk1.4  
 * jikes-classpath  
 * jikes-gij  
 * gcj-4.1  
 * sun-java5-jdk  
 * jikes-kaffe  
 * sun-java6-jdk  
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>  
bash: javac: command not found
```

When I try to update (using `sudo apt-get update`) I get:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by "can't compile"? Can't find the program javac? Errors compiling?

Comment: You have the Java runtime installed.  You probably do not have the development tools installed (where the compiler lives)

Comment: Looks like, at that point of time, the particular mirror you are using couldn't be connected to. The problem could be at either end. Did you try it again? It definitely looks like a problem with the 'apt-get update'.

Comment: Like Amit said, please try the installation again.

Comment: Still getting the same errors

Comment: The errors are stricly related to Ubuntu package management. Obviously you won't be able to compile until you get the jdk installed. Have you done "sudo apt-get update" as the error tells you to?

Comment: Yes. That's what is giving me the 'method driver' error as stated in the original post

Comment: OK, now you're really asking a different question than stated. Probably you should ask another question about why "sudo apt-get update" doesn't work, either here or on the Ubuntu forums (or on irc). Once you get that resolved, then come back to this.

Comment: As it says in the error output try sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Comment: For the apt-get error : [install `apt-transport-https`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104160/method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-https-could-not-be-found-update-error?lq=1)

Answer (score 6):

You can install the JDK on recent versions of Ubuntu by typing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

You might find this easier than attempting to set it up manually.

Comment: @danwoods: you probably haven't got an up-to-date index. Try "sudo apt-get update" and then try to install again.

Comment: Apparently the problem is bigger than I thought. I added the results of that command to my original post

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Download the Java SDK into $HOME/archives (e.g., $HOME/archives/jdk-6u16-linux-x64.bin).
2. Extract Java into /opt (or another location if you do not want to use root). For example:

```sh
cd /opt
chmod 755 $HOME/archives/jdk-6u16-linux-x64.bin
sudo $HOME/archives/jdk-6u16-linux-x64.bin</code>
```

1. Create a symbolic link (to ease upgrades):

```sh
sudo ln -s jdk1.6.0_16 jdk
```

1. Edit `$HOME/.bashrc`
2. Append the following lines:

```sh
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

1. Reload the environment variables:

```sh
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

You should now be able to compile programs.

I prefer this method to installing the managed package because uninstalling (or upgrades) never seems to remove all bits of the SDK flawlessly, and it seems to hinder installing multiple versions of the Java Software Development Kit on the same machine at the same time. I have had issues with `apt-get` and Java in the past. Also, this method allows me to be absolutely certain which version of Java is in use at any time.

If you are not comfortable using `root` and `/opt`, you can use your own account and `$HOME/bin/jdk` instead. Change the `.bashrc` file accordingly.

Remove any version of Java you previously had installed. You might need to restart your terminal session.

This works for all versions of Java since at least Java 1.2.

Comment: This method actually works. Although it may seem to be overly complex.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you will find java in the PATH and not javac in a standard Ubuntu installation. This is primarily because of the gcj package that gets installed. Symlinks are also created that can be updated using the *update-alternatives* script.

After an installation of Sun JDK, you are required to update the symlink to java, and this is usually done via a command similar to the one below

> sudo update-alternatives --config java

If hardlinks to the location of (Sun) java is not present, you can create it using a command similar to

> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_07/jre/bin/java 300

In the case of javac, you can create a symlink, again using update-alternatives using:

> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_07/bin/javac 300

This will make javac available on PATH, just like java.

Of course, there is option of updating the PATH variable via a simple export or via changes to the shell configuration file.

Comment: I don't believe this is true in the latest versions of Ubuntu. Installing as I mention above should install javac and make it accessible without any symlinks at all.

Comment: I haven't verified it on 9.04. But I've done this on versions 6.x-7.x. Probably not on 8.x. But I have the foggiest of memories for configuration issues across versions.

Comment: Well, I think 8.04 was the first version to include official sun .debs. These work much better than trying to install manually, as was necessary on previous versions.

Comment: Ah ok! I normally don't use debs for installing Java - pick the installers straight off java.sun.com.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem while installing the html validator from http://validator.nu. To install `sun-java6-jdk` I had to add this repository: `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner`

To complete the validator install, I had to set (export) my `$JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java6-sun`.

Do change "lucid" to whatever is appropriate for your Ubuntu edition.